# assigning mysql array result to php variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, curl

I am trying to send sms to all the members in a mysql table using API.

I am able to send the sms.

But only first row in the table is being used, whereas I want that the sms is sent to all the records in the table.

The code I am using is like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,mobile FROM members");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$mobile=$row[1];
$name=$row[0];

$request = "";
$param['mobileno'] = "91". $mobile;
$param['message']  = "Dear $name (organisation name) wishes you a very very Happy Birthday";
$param['username'] = "username";
$param['password']  = "password";
$param['sendername'] = "sender";
foreach ($param as $key => $val ){$request .= $key . "=" . urlencode($val);    
$request .= "&";}$request = substr( $request, 0, strlen( $request ) - 1 );
$url = "http://smsapi" . $request;
$ch = curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);exit;
curl_close( $ch );
```

I have modified the code as per the suggestions in the answers, but I am still getting the result for the first row only.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,mobile FROM members");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$mobile=$row[1];
$name=$row[0];

$request = "";
$param['mobileno'] = "91". $mobile;
$param['message']  = "Dear $name (organisation name) wishes you a very very Happy Birthday";
$param['username'] = "username";
$param['password']  = "password";
$param['sendername'] = "sender";
foreach ($param as $key => $val ){$request .= $key . "=" . urlencode($val);    
$request .= "&";}$request = substr( $request, 0, strlen( $request ) - 1 );
$url = "http://smsapi" . $request;
$ch = curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);exit;
curl_close( $ch );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) to loop through the rows.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,mobile FROM members");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$mobile=$row[1];
$name=$row[0];

$request = "";
$param['mobileno'] = "91". $mobile;
$param['message']  = "Dear $name (organisation name) wishes you a very very Happy Birthday";
$param['username'] = "username";
$param['password']  = "password";
$param['sendername'] = "sender";
foreach ($param as $key => $val ){$request .= $key . "=" . urlencode($val);    
$request .= "&";}$request = substr( $request, 0, strlen( $request ) - 1 );
$url = "http://smsapi" . $request;
$ch = curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);exit;
curl_close( $ch );
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code as above, but I am still getting the result for the first row only.

Comment: Actually the code is working OK. I think the var_dump($result);exit; was showing just one row of result, which was giving me the impression that the code is not looping through all the rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop all the rows.

something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { .... }
```

also, the php mysql extension is deprecated, have a look at mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

You're using mysql_fetch_row, which to my understanding only returns one row (if any is found). Consider using mysql_fetch_all instead